# Firebase Storage file uploading 'Connection aborted.' error

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am getting an intermittent issue while uploading a file in Firebase Storage from my Django web app-

> 'Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)

The error page from web is below-
[image: web]

Below is my code for uploading the file:

```
def upload_file(name, file_obj, file_path=None, overwrite=False, retry=True):
  if not file_path:
      file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name)
    
  if default_storage.exists(file_path) and not overwrite:
      filename = default_storage.get_available_name(name)
      file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
      default_storage.save(file_path, file_obj)
      return filename
  else:
      default_storage.save(file_path, file_obj)
      return name
```

Here my storage setting is `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'`

Is there any better solution to solve the issue other than retrying the connection?

Please suggest also if I am doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've also reported this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/291), where a GCP team member provided you with a solution.

Since you're experiencing **ConnectionError**, which is, unfortunately, not covered by [google-resumable-media-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-resumable-media-python/blob/03c11bae0c43830d539f1e0adcc837a6c88f4e2e/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py#L143), you should implement a retry for the connection errors.